# Unable to negotiate with XX.XXX.XX.XX: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss

Tags: ssh, web-hosting

I am trying to create a git repository on my web host and clone it on my computer. Here's what I did:

1. I created a repository on the remote server.
2. I generated a key pair: `ssh-keygen -t dsa`.
3. I added my key to ssh-agent.
4. I copied to the server public key in `~/.ssh`.

And then, after an attempt to run the command `git clone ssh://user@host/path-to-repository`, I get an error:

> Unable to negotiate with XX.XXX.XX.XX: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

What does that mean?

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The recent openssh version deprecated DSA keys by default. You should suggest to your GIT provider to add some reasonable host key. Relying only on DSA is not a good idea.

As a workaround, you need to tell your `ssh` client that you want to accept DSA host keys, as described in the [official documentation for legacy usage](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html). You have few possibilities, but I recommend to add these lines into your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host your-remote-host
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
```

Other possibility is to use environment variable `GIT_SSH` to specify these options:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss" git clone ssh://user@host/path-to-repository
```

Comment: If there is no such file in your .ssh directory, an empty text file named "config" will do.

Comment: Absolute perfect worked, GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss" git clone ssh://tejastank@192.168.1.4:8800/educationapp.git

Comment: As mentioned by @user2885534 you also need `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa,ssh-dss` if you want your key to be accepted when doing `git fetch` etc

Answer (score 100):

You can also add `-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss` in your ssh line:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss user@host
```

Comment: This is the quickest solution +1 because it also permanently fixes the issue for that host.  One more suggestion for the long-run is that if possible the host system should have its SSH daemon upgraded as it appears DSS it not considered very secure anymore.

Comment: @AreebSooYasir, it does _not_ permanently fix it for that host, at least in Git Bash for Windows.

Comment: In my case the connection could be established using ssh-rsa insted of ssh-dss -- it is worth mentioning that the server responded with "no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa"

Answer (score 34):

For me this worked: (added into `.ssh\config`)

```
Host *
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

Comment: The second option is not related to the problem and the first is already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Host your-host didn't work for me, provided your-host is the name of the host I'm running the ssh command from (client). But Host * worked for me.

Comment: @Krischu no, `yuor-host` is the host you are running the `ssh` against. Setting unsafe default for all the hosts is always bad idea.

Comment: @Jakuje It's not setting it to an unsafe default; it's appending to the default list as a last resort. From https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html "The '+' before the list instructs ssh to append the algorithm to the client's default set rather than replacing the default. By appending, you will automatically upgrade to the best supported algorithm when the server starts supporting it."

Comment: enabling 1k DSA keys even on last resort is not good idea. It is disabled for a good reason for years.

Answer (score 15):

If you would like to contain this security hole to a single repo,  you can add a config option to any Git repos that need this by running this command in those repos. (Note: only works with git version >= 2.10, released 2016-09-04)

```sh
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss'
```

This only works after the repo is setup, however. If you're not comfortable adding a remote manually (and just want to clone), then you can run the clone like this:

```sh
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss' git clone ssh://user@host/path-to-repository
```

Then run the first command to make it permanent.

If you don't have the latest Git and still would like to keep the hole as local as possible, I recommend putting

```sh
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss'
```

in a file somewhere, say `git_ssh_allow_dsa_keys.sh`, and `source`ing it when needed.

Answer (score 3):

I want to collaborate a little with the solution for the server side. So, the server is saying it does not support DSA, this is because the [openssh client does not activate it by default](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html):

> OpenSSH 7.0 and greater similarly disable the ssh-dss (DSA) public key algorithm. It too is weak and we recommend against its use.

So, to fix this this in the server side I should activate other Key algorithms like RSA o ECDSA. I just had this problem with a server in a lan.
I suggest the following:

Update the openssh:

```
yum update openssh-server
```

Merge new configurations in the sshd_config if there is a sshd_config.rpmnew.

Verify there are hosts keys at /etc/ssh/. If not generate new ones, see `man ssh-keygen`.

```
$ ll /etc/ssh/
total 580
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     553185 Mar  3  2017 moduli
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       1874 Mar  3  2017 ssh_config
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       4096 Apr 17 17:56 ssh_config.d
-rw-------. 1 root root       3887 Mar  3  2017 sshd_config
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    227 Aug 30 15:33 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        162 Aug 30 15:33 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    387 Aug 30 15:33 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         82 Aug 30 15:33 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys   1675 Aug 30 15:33 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        382 Aug 30 15:33 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Verify in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config the HostKey configuration. It should allow the configuration of RSA and ECDSA. (If all of them are commented by default it will allow too the RSA, see in `man sshd_config` the part of HostKey).

```
# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

For the client side, create a key for ssh (not a DSA like in the question) by just doing this:

```
ssh-keygen
```

After this, because there are more options than ssh-dss(DSA) the client openssh (>=v7) should connect with RSA or better algorithm.

[Here another good article.](https://www.smarinov.com/weblog/ssh-not-connecting/)

This is my first question answered, I welcome suggestions :D .

Answer (score 2):

In my case for bitbucket, the following worked.

```
Host yourhost(ex: bitbucket.com)
    User git
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding this `config` file, It works for me

```
Host *
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add to `vi ~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host YOUR_HOST_NAME
       HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss
   ```
2. In my case error was:

   > Unable to negotiate with IP_ADDRESS port 22: no matching host key
   > type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

   In this case it helps in `vi ~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host YOUR_HOST_NAME
       HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-dss
       PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
   ```

   So, `host key algorithm` is `ssh-dss` and `pub key` is `ssh-rsa`.

   And then I can use `ssh` for this host in normally (with out any flags).

Answer (score -4):

You either follow above approach or this one

Create the config file in the .ssh directory and add these line.

```
host xxx.xxx
 Hostname xxx.xxx
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 User xxx
 KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: That is solving completely different problem.