# git error after upgrade ubuntu to 16.04 LTS

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

After I upgrade my ubuntu to 16.04 LTS when I run git pull --rebase
I got and error

Unable to negotiate with xxx.xx.x.xx port xxxx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

my config file

```
Host [host]
    HostName [host]
    Port     [port]
    User     [user]
    HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

I have tried with [Unable to negotiate with XX.XXX.XX.XX: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208495/unable-to-negotiate-with-xx-xxx-xx-xx-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-of) wit still can not sovle.

Comment: I have tired it but still error, my problem Their offer: ssh-rsa

Comment: have you added `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` to your config?

Comment: What kind of SSH key pairs do you have in `~/.ssh/`?

Comment: I have id_rsa and  id_rsa.pub

Comment: Did you add al those config file settings after reading the other SO answer? What happens if you remove everything key-related, or everything but `+ssh-rsa`?

Comment: Which machine did you upgrade to 16.04, the server or the client?

Comment: client side from 15.10 LTS

Comment: You can try deleting `~/.ssh/known_hosts` or the line of that server within that file.

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: What SSH version do you have on both ends? Can you SSH in as a normal user?