# Gitlab autodeploy has stopped working, "no matching host key type found" error in server logs

Tags: linux, ssh, gitlab

I have .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: php:latest
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan $SSH_HOST > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd $SSH_PATH && git pull origin master"
```

It worked for several months, but stopped working about a week ago, despite there was no changes on the server.

Pipeline failed job log:

```
# mydomainproject.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd $SSH_PATH && git pull origin master"
ssh: connect to host mydomainproject.com port 22: Connection refused
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

/var/log/auth.log on the server:

```
sshd[23927]: Connection closed by 35.227.7.98 port 50036 [preauth]
sshd[23925]: Connection closed by 35.227.7.98 port 50038 [preauth]
sshd[23924]: Connection closed by 35.227.7.98 port 50040 [preauth]
sshd[23928]: Unable to negotiate with 35.227.7.98 port 50042: no matching host key type found. Their offer: sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com [preauth]
sshd[23926]: Unable to negotiate with 35.227.7.98 port 50044: no matching host key type found. Their offer: sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com [preauth]
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208495/unable-to-negotiate-with-xx-xxx-xx-xx-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-of) and tried to edit .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
script:
    - ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cd $SSH_PATH && git pull origin master"
```

It didn't help, result is the same.

I don't understand what's wrong and why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried also with `ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss`?

It's a known problem described in the OpenSSH legacy [documentation](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) even if this work-around is not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried. The result was the same.

Comment: A `ssh -vvv` from the gitlab runner to the target server gives you some hints?
The `~/.ssh/config` client side has changed? After upgrading my laptop I experienced similar issues that I solved adding `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512` to the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: > A ssh -vvv from the gitlab runner to the target server gives you some hints?
No, just "connection refused".

> The ~/.ssh/config client side has changed?
No, it hasn't.

> adding PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512 to the ~/.ssh/config file
I've tried that, no change.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem, for me it helped to manually specify the host key instead of trying to let the gitlab runner determine it on the fly with ssh-keyscan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).