# Unable to negotiate with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port xxxxx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

Tags: git, ssh

I get this message from Git, trying to fetch a remote

```
From gitlab.com:xxx/xxxxxxx
   xxxxxxxxx  master       → origin/master
 = [up to date]      dev → origin/dev
Unable to negotiate with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port xxxxx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: could not fetch production


In a case you entered incorrect password, please
update it in Keychain Access application.
```

I already tried to put in my `.ssh` folder the file `config`:

```
Host *
  HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

but didn't work.

The git remote is `ssh://yyyyyy@zzzzz.zzzzzzzz.zzz:ppppp/home/xxxxx/git/xxxxxxxxx.git`

Comment: Try `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` instead of `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`.

Comment: @ElpieKay don't work

Comment: Can it work if removing `HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes it works, but I need to limit it to one specific host

Comment: Use `Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` instead of `Host *`.

Comment: @ElpieKay  with this
```Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa```

don't work anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249508/discussion-between-fred-k-and-elpiekay).

Comment: [closely related and useful, but slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34208495/1256452) - contains link to additional background

Answer (score 1):

At the end the working code, for me, is:

```
Host zzzzz.zzzzzzzz.zzz
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

where `zzzzz.zzzzzzzz.zzz` is the remote host name. Using the IP address in place of it, didn't work.

Comment: Note that doing this risks your own system a tiny bit, and it's better to solve the problem by upgrading the ssh server on the remote host, but this workaround works fine and if you're not worried about connecting to the wrong host, the security risk is pretty small.